# add Line_Edit while program is running

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt

I am using Pyqt5 and Qt Designer to build GUIs. i want to know if there is any way to make a Gui that it can build a new line edit with a push button while running by clicking on another push button (add button for example)
a picture of what i mean new line

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add widgets to layouts that you have created with qt designer.

```
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.add_line_edit)

    def add_line_edit(self):
        line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        button.setText('Text')
        button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.print_thing(line_edit.text()))
        row = self.grid_layout.rowCount() + 1
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(line_edit, row, 0)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(button, row, 1)

    def print_thing(self, text):
        print(text)
```